# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML error causing promise rejection in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I have a React component set up to display content from a CMS, where I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. I have a standard fetch, request, receive pattern set up with a thunk to handle the async action.

The action creator looks like this:

```
export const fetchPage = (slug) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestPage());
    return fetch(`${config.api}/pages/?slug=${slug}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const status = response.status;
        switch (status) {
          case 200:
            return response.json();
          case 401:
            return Promise.reject(status);
          default:
            return Promise.reject(status);
        }
      })
      .then(json =>
        dispatch(receivePage({
          slug,
          json,
        }))
      ).catch(err =>
        dispatch(receivePageError(err)));
  };
};
```

When I first created the React component, I forgot to pass to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` the object in format `{ __html: content }` and just passed it `content`, giving me the invariant violation. What confuses me is that this error bubbled up into the redux async flow and caused a dispatch of receivePageError. Why did this error show up here, rather than in the React component itself?

Answer (score -1):

The error has been caught by the Promise's catch. The code example will console log the exception.

```js
const callAnError = () => {
  throw Error('Error');
}

const callAnErrorParent = () => {
  callAnError();
}

const callAnErrorGrandparent = () => {
  callAnErrorParent();
};

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
   callAnErrorGrandparent();
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nfyeu5co/1/

This is great resource for understanding promises

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md

Comment: Hi Matt, as indicated in the question, the original poster was already aware of what a promise is and what promise rejection entails. Please from refrain from answering questions without providing actual solutions.

Comment: The original poster asked "Why did this error show up here, rather than in the React component itself?" Which this answers. What would entail an 'actual solution' to this question?

Comment: Ahh the "redux async flow" bit sorry